# Selecting right server in google compute engine for social networking site

Tags: google-app-engine, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I've created a social networking website with the following:

1. FrontEnd: Java for web site and hybrid app for mobile.
2. Web Service: Java web service which returns JSON object.
3. BackEnd: Neo4j(nosql, graph based database).

I've decided to host this application in any cloud server. After all research I've decided to go with google compute engine. I'm expecting to receive 10 million concurrent users. Since this is a social networking website, the user will upload photos, Like, comments, blogs, chat and etc. My region is going to be Asia/Pacific. Google does provide pricing calculator. Please find the link below:

[Click Here for Compute Engine pricing calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator/)

However I do not know what configuration is required to handing these much of traffic. Please if any one of you have used google compute engine, please help me in selecting the right Servers, Persistent Disk, Load Balancing and GCE Network Bandwidth in Compute Engine Section from the above link. So that I can estimate the cost I need to spend per month.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: You question is out of scope for SO.  This site is for specific programming questions and/or  issues.

Answer (score 2):

Nobody can estimate the cost but you. We do not know how well the application was developped and how you use your resources.

Deploy your application on the Google Cloud, build a performance test plan (see tools like JMeter, LoadRunner etc) and test your different assumptions (type of VM, type of disk).

Use monitoring tools (Google Compute Engine now comes with one) to measure anything you need to know (bandwidth, CPU usage and whatnot).This will allow you to estimate the cost.

That way, you will know how much each option costs and will be able to make your own informed decision.